# Is there a metric space whose circles look like Euclidean squares?

Tags: geometry

Is there a world where circle is square? (like when triangle can have sum of degrees more than 180 on sphere)
What is the mathematical or at least common-sense proof?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a world"? Are you asking about physical reality, or just "another world" in a metaphorical sense?

Comment: user54358's answer below is a really good answer for "Is there a metric space whose circles look like Euclidean squares?" Is that what you meant to ask? Or do you really mean to find a space whose circles are also squares? You would have to explain what a square is in that space.

Comment: "Is there a metric space whose circles look like Euclidean squares?" I have meant this.

Answer (score 4):

If you define the norm to be the [maximum norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_norm), circles in that normed space would look like a square.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you paint a circle on a rubber sheet, and deform the sheet with a different deformation rate at each point until the circle becomes a square you got one. Now, you could define a bijection between both spaces.

All this assuming that what you meant is an isomorphism in between a topological space (euclidean 'rubber sheet') and another space of the same dimension.

On the other side, you can't flatten a rubber sphere into a plane.

Answer (score 0):

As Arya mentioned, in topological sense this is possible.

You can also define the distance (or "norm") in other forms, say 1-norm $|x|+|y|$ or $\infty$-norm $\max \{x,y\}$, then the circle will "look like" a square.